# Applying the chain rule for logistics differential equation, independent variable missing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Struggling to derive the logistics differential function for my second order Taylor method assessment,

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ry(1-\frac{y}{K})$$

I have never worked with an ODE where the $t$ or $x$ variable is not present in the equation, and it has me flummoxed. My lecturer pointed out that $y$ is a function of $t$, but I've still no idea how that applies to $\frac{y}{K}$.

Parameters are $0\le t\le 50$, $y(0)=100$, $r=0.1$, $K=1000$.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dt} = ry \cdot \left( 0- \frac{1\cdot K -0}{K^2} \right) = ryK $$

Where is the gap in my knowledge here? More concerned with fixing my methodology than being given the final answer itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ry(1-\frac{y}{K})$$

$$ y'=ry(1-\frac{y}{K})$$

$$y''=ry'(1-\frac {y}{K})+ry(-\frac {y'}{K})$$
$$y''=ry'(1-\frac {2y}{K})=r^2y(1-\frac{y}{K})(1-\frac {2y}{K})$$

Comment: Apologies, but what is 'k' in $\frac{2y}{k}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, for the second term $ry(-\frac{y'}{K})$ is there a rule being applied here? I can understand the first term is $ry'(u)$ where $u = (1- \frac{y}{K})$ .

Comment: Product rule of differentiation was applied and factoring.

Answer (score 1):

Hints

You don't need to apply the chain rule, since $y$ is only a function of $t$, that is, $y=y(t)$.

For constants $a$ and $b$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(ay+b\right)=ay'=a\frac{dy}{dt}$$

and for another function $g=g(t)$ depending on $t$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(yg\right)=yg'+gy'=y\frac{dg}{dt}+g\frac{dy}{dt}$$

by the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).